# EC2 instance type for drupal

Tags: drupal, amazon-ec2, selection

What are some of the checklist items for EC2 instance selection to host a drupal site hosting around 15-20 applications/websites? Need a set of checklist items to determine the correct instance type. In short, what performance items need to be considered based on the current configuration to select a EC2 instance type for migration to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this for a while. I've had no problem hosting drupal+mysql+ java webapp on a single:

m3.large, ECUs 6.5, vCPUs 2, Memory (GiB) 7.5.

Comment: Thanks Craig. How many websites were you running overhere. On what basis did you select the m3.large Ec2 instance. Do you have any checklist of items to be considered to determine the EC2 instance type ? pl. let me know.

Comment: You can find cheaper instance types with same (or even better) requirements. Check these out : https://ec2-selector.ec2-cli.com/ec2/us-east-1?api:VCpuInfo.DefaultVCpus.between=[2;undefined]&memory.between=[8;undefined]&os.in=Linux&sw.in=NA&on_demand.between=[undefined;0.1388888888888889]&columns=cur,latest,memory,api:FreeTierEligible,storage_type,on_demand,api:VCpuInfo.DefaultVCpus,api:NetworkInfo.NetworkPerformance,N1S,P1S,A1S&period=m&sorting=on_demand@ASC